# SSRS Go To URL not hyperlinking

Tags: javascript, reporting-services

Using the 'Go to URL' on SSRS,  I have created a URL with two parameters however,  this does not create a link to my drillthrough report.

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://servername/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fBI%2fSales%2fS47+Inventory+Availability+DrillThrough&rs:Command=Render&SessionID=" & Fields!SessionID.Value & " ','_blank'))"
```

When I pass the following 'Go To URL' on SSRS it does open a tab therefore I believe I may have an issue with my parameters......

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://servername/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fBI%2fSales%2fS47+Inventory+Availability+DrillThrough&rs:Command=Render"
```

I have also tried passing this URL but again, again the link on the report is not 'clickable'

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://utilityssrs1/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fBI%2fSales%2fS47+Inventory+Availability+DrillThrough&rs:Command=Render&SessionID="& Fields!SessionID.Value &"&Component="& Fields!RptComponent.Value &"'))"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The basic URL should look like this. Start with this and add the javascript wrapper after you know it's working. In fact you can just paste this into the browser address bar to check it does what you expect.

```
http://mySSRSServer/ReportServer?/MyFolder/My+Report+Name&myFirstParm=1&MySecondsParm=2
```

Once you have confirmed this works, just wrap it in the script as below, this will open it in a new tab.

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://mySSRSServer/ReportServer?/MyFolder/My+Report+Name&myFirstParm=1&MySecondsParm=2','_blank'))"
```