# SSRS - Can you pass query parameters from one rdl file to another?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, powerbi-paginated-reports

I have 2 rdl files, both have the same query parms. I want a textbox in a tablix in rpt#1 be a hyperlnk and I want to pass the value in the txtbox to one of the query parms in rpt#2. I also want to pass the query parms from rpt#1 to the other query parms of rpt#2. So when user clicks o hyperlnk, rpt#2 opens without user re-entering in parms. I assume this is done in javascript url. How would syntax of url look like?  For rpt#2, I assume I make the parms 'hidden'

Comment: You've asked the same question 3 times, you might want to consider sketching out what you expect to see, the workflow with a mock-up example so people can better understand your needs. I commented on another question but you gave no reply. Assuming I mis-understood, **EDIT** your question and provide more details.

Comment: Question has been re-edited.  Hope this helps.  My company doesn't allow uploading screenshots, files, etc.  Thanks

Comment: Draw it on paper and take a photo if you have to, but anyway... Can you not just set an action on the textbox to "Go To Report" then set each of the parameters to either the report parameters or the textbox value, I'm not sure why you think you need to build a URL ?

Comment: @AlanSchofield.  Corp Security blocks me from uploading files, images, etc.  Business requirements are that each rpt needs to open in separate windows. Hence 2 rdls, not subreport. Both rpts use query parms, not rpt parms. My understanding is that passing query parms (not rpt parms) from 1 rpt to another may not be possible. The only action options I have is 'none', 'go to bookmark', 'go to url'. Option 3 is how I am doing it. I have read that a javascript that includes url and parm names can pass the parms, but when I test it out, nothing happens when I click on url.

Comment: You can do via a URL, you just need to build the string up from either your report parameters and/or with the expression you used to set the textbox. Have look at this for the basic setup. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66589576/ssrs-go-to-url-not-hyperlinking/66592523#66592523

Comment: @Alan Schofield. Hardcoding the parm values in the url will open the rpt correctly, but when I replace the hard coded values with the query parm names from rpt 1, the rprt doesn't open. The url is ="javascript:void(window.open('https://report url&firstparm=Parameters!Parm1.Value&secondparm=Parameters!Parm2.Value','_blank'))". Since I am using query parms in both rdls, maybe the syntax needs to be difrnt for query parms vs rpt parms? Or can this even be done using query par?  And yes,am prohibited from uploading anything. I can't stick a thumb drive in pc. I can't even paste my code in this box

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use references to the actual parameter objects in your URL which you cannot do.

All you need to do is build a string up with the entire URL and use that expression as the URL.

So something like (I can't test the syntax of these at the moment but they shoudl be close enough)

```
="javascript:void(window.open('https://myReportServer/MyReport&firstparm=" & Parameters!Parm1.Value & "&secondparm=" & Parameters!Parm2.Value & "','_blank'))"
```

You just use the above as the URL expression in the action properties.

If you need to reference something from your dataset, for exmaple, if you had a list of accounts and you wanted a link for each account, then you would just reference the field instead of the report parameter values, something like.

```
="javascript:void(window.open('https://myReportServer/MyReport&firstparm=" & Parameters!Parm1.Value & "&secondparm=" & Parameters!Parm2.Value & "&accountNumber=" & Fields!AccountNumber.Value & "','_blank'))"
```

Comment: I followed the syntax. The field becomes a hyperlink but when I click on it, nothing happens. The field I am doing the action on (SSCode) is a field in a tablix and it's defined using a lookup expression.  This field value when I click on it is one of the fields I need to pass to the parameters of rpt2. The syntax of my url is "javascript:void(window.open('https://myreporturl&FromDate="&Parameters!FromDate.Value & "&SSCode=" &Fields!SSCode.Value &"','_blank'))".  Maybe fields defined using an expression can't be passed?

Comment: All you are doing is creating a string, it does not matter how you create it as long as it's correct at the end. Just create the URL by hand and make sure it works, then change your expression to produce the same string. There is nothing special happening here, just building a URL.

Comment: At risk of repeating myself forever, if you have an expression already that gives you the value you want to pass as a parameter, then just use that as part of the expression that builds the url string. I'm not sure how many different ways I can say the same thing. good luck....

Comment: The flwing post (stackoverflow.com/questions/18003013/open-ssrs-url-in-new-window) says not to include  ="javascript:void(window.open...It and others also use the rs:Command=Render in the stmnt. Maybe different ways to code this. I entered the rs:Command=Render in my hard code vrsn and it works, but not with the one I'm trying to build with yor help -> ="javascript:void(window.open('https://mySSRSServer/ReportServer?/MyFolder/My+Report+Name&QVR_Code=" & Lookup(Fields!QVR_Code.Value, Fields!QVR_Code.Value, "QVR_List_ds") & "&FromDate=" & Parameters!FromDate.Value & "','_blank))

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!!. The correct syntax (in my case) was to put a ? after the MyRptName, and I also needed to put rp: before each parm name. I read many posts and many provided alternative ways of doing this. I tried many until it worked.