# ssrs;calling drill through report via url not working with expression in string

Tags: url, reporting-services

I have an action in an SSRS report to open a drill through report.  The field in the string to build the url and pass to the parameter of the drill through report is a field that's defined as an expression in the main report. The drill thru report doesn't open, giving an error msg saying 'query execution for dataset failed'.  The url string I built is

`http://mySSRSServer/ReportServer?/MyFolder/My+Report+Name&QVR_Code=Lookup(Fields!QVR_Code.Value & Fields!Date_ID.Value,Fields!QVR_Code.Value & Fields!Date_ID.Value, Fields!QVR_Code.Value, "QVR_List_Dataset")`.

If I remove this expression in the url and just put in a QVR code value, the drill through report accepts this parameter value and runs successfully. Not sure why my expression in the url isn't accepted

pasted the expression formula from main report into url and expected drill through report to open but it doesn't

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75675555/ssrs-can-you-pass-query-parameters-from-one-rdl-file-to-another/75696216#75696216
See your same question under a different account that has the answer.

Comment: I'm trying to help, but keep hitting a brick wall. I can now see where you are going wrong but the original answer did show the correct format. I'll post an answer here too.

Answer (score 0):

If...

```
http://mySSRSServer/ReportServer?/MyFolder/My+Report+Name&QVR_Code=Lookup(Fields!QVR_Code.Value & Fields!Date_ID.Value,Fields!QVR_Code.Value & Fields!Date_ID.Value, Fields!QVR_Code.Value, "QVR_List_Dataset")
```

.. is the string you are using in the link then this will not work. You need to inject the result of your lookup expression into the string.

As an example if your look up returns a value of `ABC123` then you need to build a string that creates this

```
http://mySSRSServer/ReportServer?/MyFolder/My+Report+Name&QVR_Code=ABC123
```

So your expression needs to be

```
="http://mySSRSServer/ReportServer?/MyFolder/My+Report+Name&QVR_Code=" &
 Lookup(Fields!QVR_Code.Value & Fields!Date_ID.Value,Fields!QVR_Code.Value & Fields!Date_ID.Value, Fields!QVR_Code.Value, "QVR_List_Dataset")
```

If you use this expression as the URL value it should work. If it does not, then copy the link generated by the expression and compare it to your hardcoded version to see what needs changing.

Comment: If you reread my post, I wasn't asking how to build the url. My post already has it pasted there, and if you compare the syntax I have been posting to your solution, they match almost 100%. The only difference is that you have the & symbol after the = sign.  I'm simply asking why mine doesn't open the 2nd rpt but you seem to think I am asking how to build the url even though you already indicated how, and I have posted it already. I understand the concepts but asking why 2nd rpt doesn't open unless values are hardcoded.  I will provide both hardcoded url and what I'm trying to do

Comment: Hardcoded url that works:
https://mySSRSServer/ReportServer?/MyFolder/My+Report+Name&QVR_Code=ABC123&FromDimDate=2022-07-31&ToDimDate=2022-12-31.

What I would like:
https://mySSRSServer/ReportServer?/MyFolder/My+Report+Name&QVR_Code=& Lookup(Fields!QVR_Code.Value,Fields!QVR_Code.Value, Fields!QVR_Code.Value, "Dataset_of_QVRs")&FromDimDate=Parameters!FromDimDate.Value&ToDimDate=Parameters!ToDimDate.Value

The dates in both rdls are defined as text, not dates, and both rpts have been working fine, they just need to be linked. Even if the lookup issue is fixed, date syntax is not working.

Comment: Honestly I give up... "The only difference is that you have the & symbol after the = sign". That's THE key difference between including the actual "lookup" text in the url against including what the lookup returns. I can't help you anymore, sorry....

Comment: I just added in an image to this.  Hope this makes it easier to see so I don't have to manually type.  When I use this url, the report tries to open but nothing happens, but no error messages

Comment: The first I noticed in the image you posted shows that your expression does not start with `="` if you look at the answer I posted you see the version I did does. This make the expression static text, check my answer again. As much as you think I have something against you, I do not. I am trying to help. Nobody on StackOverflow gets paid for the many hours they spend helping others so to insinuate that I'm deliberately not being helpful is rude. Good luck with fixing your problem. Read answers and comments carefully, the answer has been stated several times.

Comment: Figured it Out!.  Just wnted to let u know I got it!. The correct syntax (in my case) was to put a ? after the MyRptName, and b4 each parm name to put rp: and that fixed it. I read many posts that provided many diffrnt ways of doing this. Tried many until it worked. Your posts didn't indicate to do this so I looked at other posts instead of solely focusing on yours. Although you say the answer has been stated several times in your posts, I don't see this. Nonetheless, I re-read some of my comments and I clearly came across 2 u as condescending and entitled. Sincere Apologies

Answer (score 0):

@Alan Schofield. Figured it Out!. Just wnted to let u know I got it!. The correct syntax (in my case) was to put a ? after the MyRptName, and b4 each parm name to put rp: and that fixed it. I read many posts that provided many diffrnt ways of doing this. Tried many until it worked. Your posts didn't indicate to do this so I looked at other posts instead of solely focusing on yours. Although you say the answer has been stated several times in your posts, I don't see this. Nonetheless, I re-read some of my comments and I clearly was condescending and entitled towards you. Sincere Apologies

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).