# SSRS;url syntax check to link 2 rdls and pass parameters

Tags: url, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008

[image]

I have received a lot of help from someone on this forum rgdng this but still this doesn't work. I think my syntax is ok but when I click on link in report, the 2nd report never opens. Attaching an image of the Action url that I have built up from my parms and the lookup expression to define the textbox. Any idea why nothing happens when I click on the link?

I have followed [the instructions in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66589576/ssrs-go-to-url-not-hyperlinking/66592523#66592523) to the best I can, but this still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax in my case was to put a `?` after the `MyRptName`, and before each parameter name to put `rp:` and that fixed it.  I read a lot of posts on this, and in the end this is what worked.